# Cant boot ubuntu grub wubi install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 which was an Wubi install so I don’t have a LiveCD.
Whenever I boot the computer it goes straight to `GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3.1`.

Is there a way that i can bypass this and boot into Ubuntu.

I am running it along side with windows vista home premium x32bit

Comment: No, he means he CAN'T get into Ubuntu so how do you expect him to get to a console, it just goes to Grub>, which is the same problem I have with my wubi 12.04. This happened to me after my graphics card overheated because the fan on it went out.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB is needed if you want to boot other Operating Systems, but it's also very usefull if you want to use more kernels, or a fallback Kernel (safe version of Ubuntu, that you can use, when your main kernel has problems).

But if even so you want to go straight to Ubuntu you can remove Grub:

Type on a console

`apt-get purge grub-common`

Removing GRUB will not let you boot into Windows Vista anymore!

I don't advise you to remove Grub.